# Error con tildes PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

Buen día, al momento de hacer un envió de datos desde javascript funcionan y se envían perfectamente las tildes pero al momento de hacer la impresión en php sale algo así:

**Texto Original**: `éstá és úná prúébá de tildes`
**Texto PHP**: `?st? ?s ?n? pr??b? de tildes`

Incluso se pierde la codificación para reconocer las vocales que llevan tilde; ya he intentado varias formas pero ninguna funciona. Agradecería ayuda de parte de ustedes.

Comment: echo utf8_decode('éstá és úná prúébá de tildes');

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base) ... Sería cuestión de indicar el charset `utf-8` tanto en el HTML como en PHP.

Comment: Hasta ese momento no he interactuado aún con la BD

Comment: Andrés, la respuesta aceptada indica **cómo resolver el problema de raíz:** sería cuestión en este caso de configurar el charset adecuado tanto en el HTML (cliente)  como en el servidor (PHP). Así no te verás obligado a ir aplicando funciones a cada salida.

Comment: Ya he intentado eso, incluso en otros módulos de el sistema funcionan las tildes correctamente

Comment: Si configuras bien el HTML con un meta adecuado y el PHP también, y quitas cualquier otra función de codificación que estés aplicando sobre los datos no debería presentarte los símbolos `?`, a no ser que haya algún conflicto en tu configuración. Convendría que pusieras en la pregunta el código que produce ese resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser un problema de charset en PHP. Probá lo siguiente usando [`header`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

También deberías chequear desde el lado del cliente, html, que tengas el mismo charset seteado.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```